# Passing textbox array to ajax json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have two different arrays namely  main_name[] and sub_name[].
I have to pass these values to the next page using AJAX, for inserting into DB.Could you please help me out, how could I pass the array as data in AJAX.
HTML

```
<input type="text" name = "main_name[]" value = "" >
<input type="text" name = "sub_name[]" value = "" >
```

JS

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
url: "response.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
data: data,
success: function(data) {
$(".the-return").html
);
alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
}
});
return false;
});
});
```

Comment: Try `data: $('form').serialize(),` in `ajax`

Comment: @Tushar could you suggest me in code format please

Answer (score 2):

`$('form').serialize()` will serialize all your form elements together with values and send along with an ajax query.

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "json",
     url: "response.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
     data: $('#form_id').serialize(),
     success: function(data) {
       $(".the-return").html
     );
     alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
    }
    });
    return false;
    });
    });
```

Comment: how to retrieve the value in response.php

Comment: You can use `$_REQUEST`. Try to `var_dump` as echo `print_r($_REQUEST, true)` on response.php

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use [serializeArray](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

```
var data = $(form).serializeArray();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "response.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        $(".the-return").html();
    }
});
```

Comment: it retuns(alerts) object

Answer (score 1):

try this it will get all values of your form in (data) variable and send through ajax in json format.

```
var data = $('form').serialize();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
url: "response.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
data: data,
success: function(data) {
$(".the-return").html
);
alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
}
});
return false;
});
});
```